# Compare char to user input char MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to use the (y/n) user input, but I'm having trouble comparing the user input to the respective character (y or n).

I have `y` and `n` defined, as well as my user input:

```
cnt        =    80

.data
tryResponse     BYTE    cnt+1   DUP(?)
yesCmp          BYTE    "y",0
noCmp           BYTE    "n",0



tryAnother proc
    try:
        mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_3
        call    WriteString
        mov     edx, OFFSET tryResponse
        mov     ecx, cnt
        call    ReadString
        mov     eax, OFFSET tryResponse
        movzx   ebx, yesCmp
        mov     edx, ebx
        call    WriteString
        movzx   ecx, noCmp
        cmp     eax, ebx
        je      yes
        cmp     eax, ecx
        je      no
    invalid:
        mov     edx, OFFSET invalid_msg
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf
        loop    try
    yes:
        jmp     main
    no:
        jmp     goodbye
tryAnother endp
```

When I try to compare the user input to `yCmp` or `nCmp`, it always returns as invalid.  I'm clearly not comparing these characters properly, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has several problems:

> ```
> movzx   ebx, yesCmp
> mov     edx, ebx
> call    WriteString
> ```

*WriteString* expects an address in the `EDX` register, but you only feed it a simple number 121 (the value of "y").

> ```
> cmp     eax, ebx
> je      yes
> cmp     eax, ecx
> je      no
> ```

In these `cmp`'s you are comparing things that cannot be compared!
The `EAX` register holds an address gotten from `mov eax, OFFSET tryResponse` while the `EBX` and `ECX` registers hold simple numbers 121 and 110 (values of "y" and "n").
The following code will work though:

```
mov     bl, yesCmp
mov     cl, noCmp
cmp     [eax], bl
je      yes
cmp     [eax], cl
je      no
```

As you can see there's no need for any `movzx` or `movsx`. The compare is done on **the 1st character only** of the input you got from the user.

---

As it is written your program will treat the uppercase characters "Y" and "N" as invalid. This might throw off your user!
The following solution is case insensitive:

```
mov     al, [eax]      ;1st character from user
or      al, 20h        ;make LCase
cmp     al, yesCmp     ;compare to "y"
je      yes
cmp     al, noCmp      ;compare to "n"
je      no
```